# xcode5: GPUImageContext.h error

Tags: ios, image, xcode5, gpuimage

If I'll run my app, this 3 errors comes up.
Does someone knows why?

[image]

Here is how I import GPUImage:

Step1 (added the GPUImage.xcodeproj file into my project):

[image]

Step2 (added the GPUImage Objects to "Target Dependencies"):

[image]

Step3 (added the libGPUImage.a file to "Link Binary With Libraries"):

[image]
[image]

Step4 (added in the Header Search Path the Source folder from GPUImage):

[image]

All in all I followed this tutorial:

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly related to what's going wrong in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916565/xcode-5-gpuimage-filter-code-errors-need-help

Comment: Some part of your includes aren't working right, if you indeed have `#import "GPUImage.h"` above this code somewhere.

Comment: How did you set up the framework? You've provided no details on the process you used. Did you use CocoaPods? Why in the world are you pointing to a GPUImage installation in /Applications? There's no reason it should be there.

Comment: Yes, I have added the frameworks which the GPUImage needs. I'm new in developing iOS Apps. What do I have to do? Can you please explain it to me step by step?

Comment: I don't know if I use CocoaPods.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you haven't described at all how you added GPUImage itself to your project. What were the exact steps you used there? Do they differ at all from the list of steps on the main page of the GitHub repository? What you have above looks very odd, if you did indeed follow each one of the installation steps.

Comment: Ok, I updated it (step by step) hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this `#import "CPUImagePicture.h"` in your .m file